# Lodash | Search object for key

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to search an object that I have for a key that matches an input name. This is so I can assign values.

`<input type="text" name="first_name"/>`

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('inputs');
const obj = {
    first_name: "Bob",
    last_name: "Marley"
};
```

I want to match the key `first_name` onto a input which has the name `first_name`.

I have got as far as:

```
_.forEach(inputs, (input) => {
    const value = _.filter(obj, input.name);
    input.value = value;
});
```

However, I keep getting undefined so I don't believe the filter is the right function to use. However, I have had a look at the documentation and not really seen anything that comes close. I have tried to convert to an array but had no hope there either as all of the keys went to the index number.

Comment: can you post the more of your code, what is obj, what is inputs

Comment: Sorry, just updated it to have more code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `_.get(obj, input.name)` is what you are looking for.

Here the docs:

```
_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])
```

> Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined,
>   the defaultValue is returned in its place.

Example:

```
const obj = {'a':1, 'b':{'c': 2}}
_.get(obj, 'a')   // returns 1
_.get(obj, 'b.c') // returns 2
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, however I get an error saying `_.get` is not a function

Comment: That was my bad! I only bought in `core` so it didn't get `_.get` thanks! Will accept as answer when I can :)